# Are there 'friendly' fire restrictions programmed into exported (american) weaponry?

Tags: united-states, war, weapons

There [appeared a claim](http://9gag.com/gag/a8jReZ3), probably in context of the turkish-russian incident:

[image: Turkish missiles or planes can't fire without American approval]

This seems too far off to be true, but it got me wondering whether nations implement precautions to prevent 'friendly' fire who export sophisticated weapons such as missiles or warplanes?

As the claim focuses on USA weapons this is my main questions, but bonus points for any other export nation such as Germany (e.g. submarines), France (e.g. carriers) or Russia (e.g. BUK-SAM).

Just to make sure that we do not end up in conspiracy-county. The evidence I would accept besides the obvious:

- incidents where weapons were taken out of commission remotely by the
  exporting nation
- incidents where weapons repeatedly did not fire on the exporting nation
- incidents where weapons where actually used ON the exporting nation (in the past decade - so [Falkland War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Sheffield_(D80)) does not count anymore)
- contracts either explicitly stating such functionality or explicitly prohibiting such

Comment: My assumption is that it is related to IFF in American-provided combat systems. This [skeptical article](http://theaviationist.com/2011/09/19/turkey-iff/) is not an answer, but I hope will help point people in their research.